# Add non-walkable endPos in Jumper pathfinding module for lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, path-finding

I'm using the ["Jumper"](https://github.com/Yonaba/Jumper) pathfinding module with Corona sdk. I'm running into a problem where for example, I need to move a unit into a building. The building tile is set to non-walkable, meaning that its walkable value=1 or not 0
So, in this case the pathfinder doesn't return a value because it doesn't accept that the endPos is non-walkable.

Here is the getPath function from the module itself:

```
    --- Calculates a `path`. Returns the `path` from location __[startX, startY]__ to location __[endX, endY]__.
  -- Both locations must exist on the collision map. The starting location can be unwalkable.
  -- @class function
  -- @tparam int startX the x-coordinate for the starting location
  -- @tparam int startY the y-coordinate for the starting location
  -- @tparam int endX the x-coordinate for the goal location
  -- @tparam int endY the y-coordinate for the goal location
  -- @tparam int clearance the amount of clearance (i.e the pathing agent size) to consider
  -- @treturn path a path (array of nodes) when found, otherwise nil
    -- @usage local path = myFinder:getPath(1,1,5,5)

  function Pathfinder:getPath(startX, startY, endX, endY, clearance)
        self:reset()
    local startNode = self._grid:getNodeAt(startX, startY)
    local endNode = self._grid:getNodeAt(endX, endY)
    assert(startNode, ('Invalid location [%d, %d]'):format(startX, startY))
    assert(endNode and self._grid:isWalkableAt(endX, endY),
      ('Invalid or unreachable location [%d, %d]'):format(endX, endY))
    local _endNode = Finders[self._finder](self, startNode, endNode, clearance, toClear)
    if _endNode then
            return Utils.traceBackPath(self, _endNode, startNode)
    end
    return nil
  end
```

I tried to remove the assert part where it checks if the endPos is walkable, but it didn't do anything.

What I need is to add the endPos to the path even if it's non-walkable

I'm not very good at algorithms, so if anyone knows how to achieve this I would appreciate it.

Comment: You could provide more information about "but it didn't do anything". Modification like that must have changed behavior of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `map` you provide for `Grid` function instead of body of `Pathfinder` function:

```
local board  = { 
    tiles = {}, 
    walkable = 0, 
    map = {
        {0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
    } 
}

-- Make it walkable
board.map[1][2] = 0

local function createPath( startx, starty, endx, endy )

    -- Creates a grid object
    local grid = Grid( board.map ) 
    -- Creates a pathfinder object using Jump Point Search
    local myFinder = Pathfinder( grid, 'JPS', board.walkable ) 
    -- Calculates the path, and its length
    local path = myFinder:getPath( startx, starty, endx, endy )

    return path

end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get this. Are you saying that I simply have to make the endPos a walkable tile so it gets accepted by the pathfinder?
If so, then it's not a valid solution.